# Problem with deploy react app with gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I've got a problem with deploying my react app with gh-pages. I tried all guides from YT and those from the first site of Google. And my GitHub pages don't show an app still. link to my repo:
https://github.com/maksymilianMroz/react-todo-app

the question is Where is the problem? I didnt write smth in the code? How can I fix this? (I want to live preview on my react app by ghpages)

Comment: hello, what is the question ?

Comment: oh, sorry the question is Where is the problem? I didnt write smth in the code? How can I fix this? (I want to live preview on my react app by ghpages)

Comment: But what were you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your project site https://maksymilianmroz.github.io/react-todo-app/ and do a full refresh with the developer tools of your browser enabled, you will see that all javascript and css references result in a 404. This is because all url all prefixed with `maksymilianMroz`.

eg https://maksymilianmroz.github.io/maksymilianMroz/react-todo-app/static/css/main.fbf7fb8c.chunk.css

where it should be https://maksymilianmroz.github.io/react-todo-app/static/css/main.fbf7fb8c.chunk.css

This is caused by the homepage property of your package.json file, as shown in the output of `npm run build`

[image]

If you adjust that property in the package.json your build will be fine.

```
{
  "name": "react-todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://maksymilianMroz.github.io/react-todo-app",
  ...
}
```